# Is it possible to use dplyr::select to select columns and update at the same time?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

Sample dataset:

```
a = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4),b = c('1','2','3','4'),c=c('6','6','6','6'))
```

What I want to do is:

1. select the `b` and `c` from dataframe `a`;
2. change the class of `b` and `c` from character to numeric

The code that I tried:

```
a %>% select(b,c) %<>% as.numeric
```

The error appeared:

```
Error in a %>% select(b, c) %<>% as.numeric : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
Warning: cannot xtfrm data frames
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `mutate` with `across` as `as.numeric` expects a `vector` as input and not a data.frame or list

```
library(magrittr)
a %<>%    
     mutate(across(where(is.character), as.numeric))
```

-output

```
> str(a)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: num  1 2 3 4
 $ b: num  1 2 3 4
 $ c: num  6 6 6 6
```

---

Or use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
 setDT(a)[, (2:3) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = is.character ]
```

-output

```
> str(a)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: num  1 2 3 4
 $ b: num  1 2 3 4
 $ c: num  6 6 6 6
```

---

Or another option is to automatically convert to its type based on the value with `type.convert`

```
a %<>%
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: Is it possible to edit the original dataframe by pipeline operator and without using any dummy variables(i.e. df2)? My computer only has 8gb ram, so I hope not to use dummy variables...

Comment: Something like inplace  = true in pandas

Comment: The update returns b and c only... What I want is a dataframe with numeric a, numeric b and numeric c...

Comment: @doraemon i got confused by your `select` step in your post. Try the update

Comment: Is it possible to subset by column names...? I tried to use "[" to subset the columns by names, but fail

Comment: @doraemon. Yes, you can use `a[, c("b", "c")]`